# "Meteorify" a cloned project

Tags: github, meteor

I uploaded a project to Github. Now, I want to download it from another Computer, and run it.

I can do this

> git clone [...etc ...]

without any problems. But when I run

```
meteor
```

in the directory, the output is "You're not in a Meteor project directory."

How can I do to "Meteorify" a project?

The repository to "Meteorify" is this: https://github.com/Nullpo/FerNet

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that repository missing the `.meteor` folder? I don't think it's a meteor project without it. You'd need to recreate it (`meteor create FerNet` and then copy files into that directory).

Comment: For others that may run into this: make sure you have a `.meteor/packages` file, even if nothing is in it to begin with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project should work out of the box. If it doesn't, make sure you've got all the necessary files (`.meteor` folder) copied, and not lost due to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it was that :)

Comment: Should the .meteor folder really be part of the repository? Isn't it better to just have your own code at the repository, and one .meteor folder at each computer?

Comment: @PeppeL-G The .meteor directory contains the local metadata for the project, not the Meteor installation (you may be thinking of `~user/.meteor`.) In particular, it stores the Meteor version and packages that are used.

Comment: @AndrewMao My `.meteor` folder seems to be 141MB big, guess it would be good to avoid syncing that. Can't version and packages be specified in the `smart.json` file? Your collections data won't be synced, though :/

Comment: @PeppeL-G your `.meteor` folder contains a `.gitignore` and won't send the `.build` directory which is why it's so big.

Comment: @AndrewMao I see. Then you're guys been right all along. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your project doesn't have the `.meteor` directory committed. Make sure that you add and commit that as well, and it will work as normal.